# Python: How to get all the parent classes and function names in one array within that function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

What I tried:

```
import inspect

class ClassA:
    class ClassB:
        def FunctionC():
            print(inspect.stack()[0][3])    # returns 'FunctionC'

ClassA.ClassB.FunctionC()
```

This only returns the current function name, what I need is all the parent classes and function names inside one array.
I mean something like this:

```
output = ['ClassA', 'ClassB', 'FunctionC']
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [inspect.stack()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack) has an `code_context` attribute that contains this information. This can also be accessed through `inspect.stack()[1][4]`, if you'd prefer.

```py
import inspect

class ClassA:
    class ClassB:
        @staticmethod
        def FunctionC():
            context = inspect.stack()[1].code_context[0].replace('\n', '')
            print(context.split('.'))


ClassA.ClassB.FunctionC()
```

Comment: This is only the information obtained by simply reading the source code file. When you use `func = ClassA.ClassB.FunctionC` and `func()`, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is just temporarily possible way try this.

```
inspect.getmembers(ClassA.ClassB)[0][1]
```

@Mechanic Pig say right thing. Either this ways is only possible in function is working under structure of ClassA.ClassB.FunctionC